# Swift Autolayouts constant change when keyboard is open programmatically

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am using Autolayout , on this page tableview and view with textfield.  when keyboard gets opened then child view and tableview constant should change .The problem is in my code Only **Child View** is slide up but tableview doesn't.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification?) {

        guard let keyboardFrame = (notification?.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue(),
            duration:NSTimeInterval = notification?.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {
            return
        }

        bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 10
         BotTbl.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 10

        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            duration,
            animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            },completion:nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification?) {
        guard let duration = (notification?.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double) else {
            return
        }

        bottomConstraint.constant = 0
        BotTbl.constant = 10

        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            duration,
            animations:{
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            },
            completion:nil)
    }
```

[image]